# Parity: if I don't include --no-ancient-blocks will it download blocks all the way back to genesis (after the initial sync)?

Tags: parity

In other words, if I have less than 1.5TB to play with, is  --no-ancient-blocks essential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with or without warp, unless you are running `--pruning archive` you should only be using around 150gb at the moment. (https://wiki.parity.io/FAQ#what-are-the-parity-ethereum-disk-space-needs-and-overall-hardware-requirements) Regardless of whether or not you warp sync, you download all blocks from genesis.

A common misunderstanding however, is that blocks contain state information, and you require every state since genesis to have a full node. Blocks only contain *transactions* which *act on the state*. An archive node (the 1.5TB you are referring to) keeps *every intermediate version of the state* which is not necessary.

`--no-ancient-blocks` is less secure than a light client and is not recommended. It will however, drop your storage requirements to a few tens of GB. That means you grab a snapshot (including a recent state) and never check blocks before it to verify that the snapshot was valid. Warp sync doesn't calculate state for historical blocks, only verifying difficulty.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. Also you answered the question that I asked on a comment on the other page (the difference between archive mode and not), so please ignore that :)